# Regex for url matching and rewriting

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

Hello I am trying to create a regex that will match on the following

`/go/brand`

but not match

`/go/brand/anotherpage`

I was thinking that I could use something like the following

`^go/([_0-9a-z-]+)(?!/)`

where I don't match anything that has a slash after brand (brand can by dynamic).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ^go\/([_0-9a-z-]+)[^\/]\/ this is super close but it matches /go/brand/ and does not match /go/brand i would like the reverse of this.   So i need it to match /go/brand and not /go/brand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an end-of-string anchor:

```
^/go/([\w-]+)(?!/)$
```

This works for me in [RegExr](http://regexr.com?33bm8), but perhaps your URL rewriting regex engine has additional nuances you'll need to accommodate.

Comment: this worked flawlessly thank you very much!  My regex foo is horrible.

Comment: would it also be possible to match this: /go/brand and /go/brand/ but not /go/brand/somethingelse

Comment: That's actually easier: `^/go/([\w-]+)/?$`, where the capturing group won't include the final slash.

Comment: ...Thinking about it, the first one doesn't need the negative lookahead, either: simply `^/go/([\w-]+)$` would have worked. (Must have been one of those days!!)

Answer (score 1):

```
^/go/[^/]+$
```

The first two `/` will need to be escaped if `/` is used as the regex delimiter, i.e. `/^\/go\/[^/]+$/`